# How to get the startup time of his own discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Does someone know how to get the startup time of his own discord bot? ( i don't mean the uptime) (i am looking for the startup time)

Something like that:

in a variable.

Start time
2020-12-31 12:12:12

Comment: Do you when he starts being online or when he first started?

Comment: when he starts being online

Answer (score 0):

You can use this event to detect when he's online:

```
let _date;

client.once("ready", () => {
    _date = new Date();
    console.log(_date);
});
```

Comment: I've edited it now. This creates a variable that is accessible from outside the ready method. Just check if _date is not null if you print it somewhere different than the ready method.

Comment: Hey Steven, idk what i am doing but i got a problem. I am to dump to get _date to a diffrent js file. it says [object object] you know a solution?

Comment: Can you share your source code? Or did you make that variable available in the different file?

Answer (score 0):

```
const { CommandoClient, Client } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { Structures } = require('discord.js');
const discord = require('discord.js');
const path = require('path');
const { prefix, token, discord_owner_id } = require('./config.json');
const bot = new Client();

Structures.extend('Guild', function(Guild) {
  class MusicGuild extends Guild {
    constructor(client, data) {
      super(client, data);
      this.musicData = {
        queue: [],
        isPlaying: false,
        nowPlaying: null,
        songDispatcher: null,
        volume: 1
      };
      this.triviaData = {
        isTriviaRunning: false,
        wasTriviaEndCalled: false,
        triviaQueue: [],
        triviaScore: new Map()
      };
    }
  }
  return MusicGuild;
});

const client = new CommandoClient({
  commandPrefix: prefix,
  owner: discord_owner_id // value comes from config.json
});

client.registry
  .registerDefaultTypes()
  .registerGroups([
    ['music', 'Music Command Group'],
    ['gifs', 'Gif Command Group'],
    ['other', 'random types of commands group'],
    ['guild', 'guild related commands']
  ])
  .registerDefaultGroups()
  .registerDefaultCommands({
    eval: false,
    prefix: false,
    commandState: false
  })
  
  .registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, 'commands'));


  
let _date;

  client.on("ready", () =>{
    _date = new Date();
    console.log(_date)
    console.log('Startet Up :) !')
    client.user.setStatus('dnd')
    client.user.setActivity('Simogus Livestream', {type: 'WATCHING'}, {url: 'www.twitch.tv/simogu'}).catch(console.error);
});



client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (___, newState) => {
  if (
    newState.member.user.bot &&
    !newState.channelID &&
    newState.guild.musicData.songDispatcher &&
    newState.member.user.id == client.user.id
  ) {
    newState.guild.musicData.queue.length = 0;
    newState.guild.musicData.songDispatcher.end();
    return;
  }
  if (
    newState.member.user.bot &&
    newState.channelID &&
    newState.member.user.id == client.user.id &&
    !newState.selfDeaf
  ) {
    newState.setSelfDeaf(true);
  }
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'Allgemein'); // change this to the channel name you want to send the greeting to
  if (!channel) return;
  channel.send(`Willkommen ${member} auf den Server von den Kings  !`);
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: `const duration =  moment.duration(client.uptime, milliseconds).format(" D [days], H [hrs], m [mins], s [secs]");` This should work. And please don't create an answer to paste the code, just append it to your existing answer or otherwise I won't get notified.

Comment: idk but ti says : milliseconds is not defined

Comment: Then we have to parse the milliseconds to seconds:
`const duration =  moment.duration(Math.floor((client.uptime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000), seconds).format(" D [days], H [hrs], m [mins], s [secs]");`

Comment: Is there something wrong: now it says second is not defined |

const moment = require("moment"); 
const momentDurationFormatSetup = require("moment-duration-format"); 
momentDurationFormatSetup(moment);

Comment: I forgot, that you should put `seconds` in quotes. So it should be `const duration =  moment.duration(Math.floor((client.uptime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000), "seconds").format(" D [days], H [hrs], m [mins], s [secs]");`

Comment: i think something is broken with my bot maybe you can try if you got one but idk, but for real thanks man, you helped me understanding js a lot or the moment resource is not working right

Comment: I can try to build that bot this evening. I can also explain it to you in Discord. I think you speak German, do you?

Comment: Because of that, I can talk German with you. But I think it's prohibited here to write another language than English.

Comment: You only need a bit experience with JS and you should be able to read API's. That's it.

Comment: yeah i know, but can you tell me from where you got that knowledge?, school, self learned?

Comment: I've taught myself through YouTube and some websites.

Comment: okay gonna try that too, when you got time pls try that you tell me, again thanks for helping again if you want to write me faster or better communication my dc: Lucky恵#2825